# android native crash libart.so libc.so

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there anyone who can give me some clues about this [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3EP6.png)?
I will appreciate that very much!

```html
11-06 11:12:43.375 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-06 11:12:43.375 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/land/land:6.0.1/MMB29M/V8.2.3.0.MALCNDL:user/release-keys'
11-06 11:12:43.375 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
11-06 11:12:43.375 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
11-06 11:12:43.375 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG: pid: 375, tid: 2165, name: Thread-20311  >>> com.sunlike <<<
11-06 11:12:43.375 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xb8
11-06 11:12:43.431 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'art/runtime/thread.cc:1238] Native thread exited without calling DetachCurrentThread: Thread[54,tid=2165,Native,Thread*=0x556f0c60a0,peer=0x132302e0,"Thread-20311"]'
11-06 11:12:43.431 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007f9c6f6dd9  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000000000000016  x3   0000007f9c6f6dd9
11-06 11:12:43.431 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000016  x5   0000007fb58e0640  x6   0000000000000016  x7   0000000000000000
11-06 11:12:43.431 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000007f9c6f6def  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000010
11-06 11:12:43.431 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000007fb2569b70  x13  0000000000000000  x14  000000000000002c  x15  0000007fb2569bb0
11-06 11:12:43.431 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007fb256d9f0  x17  0000007fb584a100  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000007f9c6f6d98
11-06 11:12:43.431 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007f9c6f6d90  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000007fb2569ae0  x23  0000007f9c6f6d78
11-06 11:12:43.432 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007f9c6f6d48  x25  0000007fb256e000  x26  0000007fb256e000  x27  0000007fb256e000
11-06 11:12:43.432 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000007f9c6f7188  x29  0000007f9c6f6c70  x30  0000007fb23a4f0c
11-06 11:12:43.432 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f9c6f6c70  pc   0000007fb23a4f20  pstate 0000000080000000
11-06 11:12:43.450 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
11-06 11:12:43.451 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000465f20  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+304)
11-06 11:12:43.451 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000466fc0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+276)
11-06 11:12:43.452 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000046770c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+204)
11-06 11:12:43.452 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000004328c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+560)
11-06 11:12:43.452 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000001362a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+3136)
11-06 11:12:43.452 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000004561e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread18ThreadExitCallbackEPv+240)
11-06 11:12:43.452 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000000000068160  /system/lib64/libc.so (_Z21pthread_key_clean_allv+160)
11-06 11:12:43.452 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000067ca0  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_exit+72)
11-06 11:12:43.452 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00000000000677c8  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+56)
11-06 11:12:43.452 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000000000001c644  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
11-06 11:12:44.513 15398-15398/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_09
11-06 11:12:44.513 15398-15398/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
11-06 11:12:44.561 1296-20463/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0
```

My bad! Here is the error log with text.

Comment: DO not post images of code or errors.  Post the actual text here.

Comment: What does this have to do with the NDK?